# Parsing XML into existing objects in golang

Tags: xml, go, protocol-buffers

I'm using `protobuf` in Go to send data between microservices, and I have a question about an adapter I'm currently building.

I have `protobuf` objects created using `protoc` in the target system. Now I have XML files provided by an external party that I want to translate into those `protobuf` objects and send them in.

In general when parsing XML in Go, you would obviously do something like:

```
type MyType struct {
    MyValue string `xml:"my_value,attr"`
}
```

However, since I already gave the objects, I would like to avoid having to duplicate them all just to have to do something like:

```
func main() {
    mt := mt.Parse()

    pbobj.MyValue      = mt.MyValue
    pbobj.MyOtherValue = mt.MyOtherValue
    // and on and on and on
}
```

What is the best way to handle this? Should I create duplicate objects and map them, or can I just apply some kind of XML-tag mapper to the already-existing objects created from `protoc`?

Thanks.